# Haskell -> After parsing how to work with strings

Tags: parsing, haskell

Hello
after doing the parsing with a script in Haskell I got a file with the 'appearance' of lists of strings. However when I call the file content with the function ***getContents*** or ***hGetContents***, ie, reading the contents I get something like: String with lines (schematically what I want is: **"**[" aaa "," bbb "" ccc "]**"** -> ["aaa", "bbb" "ccc"]). I have tried with the ***read*** function but without results. I need to work with these lists of strings to concatenating them all in a single list.

I'm using the lines function, but I think it only 'works' one line at a time, doesn't it?
**What I need is a function that verify if an element of a line is repeted on other line**. If I could have a list of a list of strings it could be easier (but what I have is a line of a string that looks like a list of strings) 
Regards
Thanks.

Comment: To help us answer questions like this better, always provide at least an error message.  "Without results" is incredibly vague, and from your description the problem could be pretty much anything.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input? I'm having a hard time understanding. Are you looking to turn each line of the file into a list of strings, so that you end up with is `[[String]]`?

Comment: I have a file with the results of a lot of inscriptions (of participants) in a future meeting.
This file has the structure of CSV (comma separated values). After making parsing the contents of the file becomes somtehing like this:
["name1","email1@mail.com","phone1","age1","company1"]
["name2","email2@mail.com","phone2","age2","company2"]
["name1","email1@mail.com","phone1","age1","company1"]
["name3","email3@mail.com","phone3","age3","company3"]
Now I need to handle data entry and the best would be something like:

Comment: [["name1","email1@mail.com","phone1","age1","company1"],["name2","email2@mail.com","phone2","age2","company2"],["name1","email1@mail.com","phone1","age1","company1"],["name3","email3@mail.com","phone3","age3","company3"]]
something like :: [[String]]. But what I have above is :: String splited into multiple lines.
This string can be divided into lines - lines function - but each line  ["namex","emailx@mail.com","phonex","agex","companyx"] is a string. 
I need to convert the line to a list of strings :: [String] and all the content of the file :: [[String]].

Comment: If I use the function read (read line:: [String]) for each line I get error due to lack of \ "For example:
- To check if there are repeated entries to verify that the email address is being duplicated in another row.
- to see how many participants also belong to a particular company.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried with the read function but without results

Just tested, and it works fine:

```
Prelude> read "[\"aaa\",\"bbb\",\"ccc\"]" :: [String]
["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
```

Note that you need to give the return type explicitly, since it can't be determined from the type of the argument.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine; but I need get the content of the file and it doesn't have the '\' (slash); how can I read (convert) from a line?    I mean, all the content of the file is treated as a string divided by lines (in each line we have something that looks like a list of strings but is a string).

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is the [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3alines) function from `Data.List` (reexported by the `Prelude`) that breaks up a multi-line string into a list of strings.

Comment: Thanks Cactus, I'm using the lines function, but I think it only 'works' one line at a time, doesn't it?
What I need is a function that verify if an element of a line is repeted on other line. If I could have a list of a list of strings it could be easier (but what I have is a line of a string that looks like a list of strings) 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

in my understanding, what you can do is

create a function that receives a list of lists, each list is a line of the entire string, of the argument passed in, and checks if a element of a line occurs in other line.

then, this function passes the entire string, separated by lines using [lines][1].

Comment: Thanks, but how can I check if an element is in other line; because I only can handle one line at a time? Example: \n                          
first input =  unlines eachLine \n
    where allLines = lines input;  \n
       eachLine  = map listStr  allLines \n
Another thing is that if I create a function that receives a list of list (of strings) but I only can pass a string (each line)  (Please note that in the code above \n is for break the line)